# When I try to print the an object I only get its location in memory. What is wrong with my ToString?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The ToString in the parent class works fine and everything is imported correctly from the parent module (I get no errors). When I try to print an object, I get <**main**.HourlyEmp object at 0x02E73F70> instead of the data members. Any Ideas?

```
import employeeClass

#hourly Employee
class HourlyEmp(employeeClass.Employee):

    #constructer
    def __init__(self, FName, LName, address, phoneNum, EType, payRate, EID = employeeClass.Employee.employeeNum):
        super(HourlyEmp, self).__init__(FName, LName, address, phoneNum, EType, EID = employeeClass.Employee.employeeNum)
        self.__payRate = payRate

    #toString
    def __str__(self):
        output = ""
        output += super(employeeClass.Employee, self).__str__()
        output += "\nPayrate: " + str(self.__payRate)
        return output

    #getter
    def getPayRate(self):
        return self.__payRate

    #setter
    def setRate(self, newRate):
        dataType = str(type(newRate))
        #checks if newRate is an int or a float
        types = [str(type(5)), str(type(5.5))]
        if newRate == "" or dataType not in types:
            print("This is not a valid rate.")
        else:
            self.__payRate = newRate
```

Comment: please post the entire class code including current indentation

Comment: I'm willing to bet the that `Employee` super call is not implemented for the method.

Comment: @CraigBurgler I added the rest of the class

Comment: and what do you mean @MalikBrahimi

Comment: At the very least, you are passing the wrong class to the call to `super`; it should be `HourlyEmp`, not `employeeClass.Employee`.

Comment: Does the parent `Employee` class actually contain a `__str__` method?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi yes it does.

Comment: @chepner No because `__str__` is implicitly derived from `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `super(...).__str__` used the wrong class as a starting point in the attribute lookup. I'm not sure *why* that produced the observed output, but

```
output += super(employeeClass.Employee, self).__str__()
```

should be

```
output += super(HourlyEmp, self).__str__()
```